# How to use option buttons to change a value in a Word 2016 table

Tags: vba, ms-word, radio-button

I am attempting to create a form that uses option buttons to assign a score, which would later be totaled for evaluation purposes. (I am using Word 2016 on Windows 10.)
Here is a pic of a portion of the proposed form, with 5 columns:[Proposed Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h03XQ.png)

Here is a picture of the code I have attempted to use, which worked just exactly as I wanted it to **"in EXCEL."** Due to needs in other parts of the form, however we will be using Word, not Excel.[Code Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohkcJ.png)

Since we've decided to use Word, due to other features that Excel lacks, what code should I be using that would place a point value in the "Points" column? (I am assuming e2 to be the address of the 2nd row, 5th column?). I have spent 2 days so far trying to understand how to make this work. I know it can be done, but I lack the specific coding knowledge to make it happen. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-option-buttons-to-change-a-value-in-a-word/b352be92-a086-4d7e-a774-809fd8e280dc. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using both formfields and ActiveX controls. It would be far simpler to use just formfields and, instead of having radio buttons, a simple dropdown for each item. That way, you don't need all those separate columns and the results could be tallied from the dropdown selections without the need for VBA.